# Keeping a reference to a vector element valid after resizing

Tags: c++, vector, reference

If we make a reference to a vector element and then resize the vector, the reference is no longer valid, the same happens with an iterator:

```
std::vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int& ref = vec[0];
auto itr = vec.begin();

cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << endl;

vec[0] = 7;

cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << endl;

vec.resize(100);
vec[0] = 3;

cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << endl;
```

Prints out:

```
0 0
7 7
0 0 // We expected a 3 here
```

And I know that it would be more practical to just keep a reference to the vector itself and call vec[0], but just for the sake of questioning, is it possible to keep an object that will always be vec[0] even if the object is moved?

I've tried writing a small helper class to help with this, but I'm unsure if this is the best method or if it can even fail?

```
template<typename T>
struct HelperClass
{
    std::vector<T>& vec;
    size_t element;

    HelperClass(std::vector<T>& vec_, size_t element_) : vec(vec_) , element(element_) {}

    // Either define an implicit conversion from HelperClass to T
    // or a 'dereference' operator that returns vec[0]
    operator T&() { return vec.at(element); }
    T& operator*() { return vec.at(element); }
};
```

And use it by either the implicit conversion to T& or by the 'dereference' operator:

```
std::vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int& ref = vec[0];
auto itr = vec.begin();
HelperClass<int> hlp = HelperClass<int>(vec, 0); // HelperClass

cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << " " << hlp << " " << *hlp << endl;

vec[0] = 7;

cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << " " << hlp << " " << *hlp << endl;

vec.resize(100);
vec[0] = 3;

cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << " " << hlp << " " << *hlp << endl;
```

Which already prints what was excepted:

```
0 0 0 0 
7 7 7 7
0 0 3 3
```

So is there a better way to do this aside from having a helper class and can the helper class be unreliable in some cases?

I've also come across [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/3xmpz9/holding_reference_or_pointer_of_a_vector_element/) thread in reddit, but it seems that they do not discuss the helper class there

Comment: A reference is implemented using a pointer. Anything that relocates the data in memory invalidates it, and resizing an array may need to reallocate.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, I'm just asking if it's possible to keep an object that acts as a reference that doesn't get invalidated when the memory reallocates such as this helper class, it's also possible I phrased the title wrong, I'm unsure of what would be a better title though.

Comment: you can also refer to [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) on how you can use it.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref). Unlike a traditional reference, a `std::reference_wrapper` can be rebound.  So you can grab a reference to the desired `vector` element, and after resizing the vector, grab a new reference to the same element again.

Comment: The `int` (or more accurately, `size_t`) **is** the "reference" you are looking for, and the syntax to "dereference" it is `vec[i]`.  The "helper class" does the job

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I tried std::reference_wrapper, but it doesn't seem to be able to do what I need, since what it does is, effectively, create a vector of references to another STL Container, and even if I keep a reference to the 0th member of this vector of references, when the original vector is resized the vector of references becomes invalid, so I'd have to update the new vector and then again update the object that keeps the reference, what I'm hoping to do here is keep an object that doesn't need to update when the original vector updates, such as my helper class.

Comment: Your helper "works" only because it accesses the `vector` by indexes and not references. Every time you access the helper, it re-evaluates the current element at a given index, which is OK as long as that index does not go out of bounds after a resize occurs. Nothing in the STL will do that same thing for you, so yes, you need to write your own helper to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing you could do is have a vector of pointers rather than a vector of instances. That of course has its own passel of issues but if you must have object references survive a vector resize that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Any reallocation of the vector will invalidate any pointers, references and iterators.

In your example, your `HelperClass` is useless in sense that this:

```
cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << " " << hlp << " " << *hlp << endl;
```

is  the same as:

```
cout <<  ref << " " << *itr << " " << vec[0] << " " << vec[0] << endl;
```

If a reallocation happens, just use the iterator interface `.begin()` `.end()` to access again the iterators.

Comment: I know that I could just use vec[0], but that would mean that I'd need to have the object vec or a reference/pointer to it, if I want, for example, to give a function a reference to only the nth element, instead of the whole vector, I can only think of using this helper class to do it.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues: If the function only gets a reference and doesn't have access to the `vector`... who *resizes* it? Because if that function can call some other function that does have access to the `vector`, why can't it access the `vector` itself?

Comment: @NicolBolas If the program is multi threaded, for example, while one function adds items to the vector, another works with an item of that function.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues You can't do that. Even if you hold a pointer to a single element in the vector, any reallocation of the vector will invalidate that pointer.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues you can't do that, vector is not `thread safe`

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues: "*If the program is multi threaded, for example, while one function adds items to the vector, another works with an item of that function.*" Then you need to have some kind of `mutex`, because two different threads cannot access the same `vector` at the same time. So when you call that function and pass it a reference, the `mutex` for the `vector` should remain locked, thus preventing other threads from resizing it.

Comment: @KostasRim, but if you pass the helper object to a function (and make the vec and element private, unlike I did), then the function has access to only that element of the vector, even when it's changed, and doesn't know about the whole vector itself.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues: And FYI: the helper class from Reddit? It won't help with a multithread situation, because by the time the helper class fetches the reference, it could already be invalidated. This is why you have to lock multi-threaded access to the same `vector`. Or any container, for that matter.

Comment: @KostasRim I suppose the multithreaded example doesn't work then, since it's unsafe, and aside from that, it's true that nothing else could modify the vector, so I suppose it might be impossible to have it resized while working on it, but possibly another use case is if a class asks for a certain element and wants to keep it for it's lifetime, occasionally using it, but it doesn't want to constantly update it, as the vector gets resized in another operation, but it also doesn't want to keep a reference to vector itself since it really only needs that 1 element.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues: Then it's going to have to keep a reference to the `vector`, either directly or indirectly (through a helper object that contains the reference). That's just how `vector` works.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right, but if possible I'd like to make it not know that vector exists, yet being able to access the one specific element, I suppose that then the best would be to have the helper class only exposes an operator* which returned the element but never exposed the vector reference, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep the index, which shouldn't change after resize to bigger.